# Did Kurama become a whole after the last war?

Tags: naruto

Did Kurama get his half from Minato and become a whole after the war? Thus, in *Boruto*, is Kurama composed of yin and yang already?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

During the war, Black Zetsu absorbs Minato's half of Kurama -- Minato tries to revive Naruto (from whom the other half was just extracted by Madara), but Zetsu steals it, and that is how the Gedo Statue becomes complete. Here is that particular scene on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/7MdnW4i6FWg).

After the war, the "whole" Kurama goes back inside Naruto.

Comment: Obito took control after Black Zetsu stole Minato's half, stole part of 1 and 8 tails from Madara, and then with help from Kakashi warped to his dimension with Naruto and injected them back in. Recall right before the final battle, Kurama was free and then sealed into a planetary devistation, AND Naruto used Kurama during that very battle.